# Visual Studio C# Opening forms in the same window (splash screen into title screen of game)

Tags: c#, winforms, game-development

Sorry if I'm not communicating this correctly, I'm new to programming in C# and visual studio so I'm having trouble translating abstract thought into objective code.

What I'm trying to do is open different forms in the same window. I have a splash screen on a timer that's set to go to the next form. What I'm trying to make a splash screen that opens into a game's title screen (think minecraft's mojang logo which opens to the main menu). so the code I'm working with so far is

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        titlescreen Check = new titlescreen();
        Check.Show();
        Hide();
        timer1.Stop();
```

What I"m trying to is make a splash screen for my company's logo that then opens into the main menu, but it's opening the titlescreen form as a separate window.

How would I make these screens stay in the same window?

Comment: You need to DOCK the form.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You only really have half an answer. The soulition WAS to dock, but I had to dock panels to the form, not using two different forms. Unless your solution was correct, but saying 'dock them' doesn't really tell me anything

Comment: I got you to the correct answer.  Before my response you did even know to dock.